# comma before relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, commas, restrictive-clauses

I think a comma is necessary in such phrases because "that restaurant" is only one here:

> **A**: Have you been to that restaurant, which is popular among young people?
>
> **B**: Yes, I have.  I enjoyed lunch there.

Can I write it without comma like this?  Isn't it necessary to put commas before some certain relative clauses?

> **A**: Have you been to that restaurant which is popular among young people?
>
> **B**: Yes, I have.  I enjoyed lunch there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. There are two types of relative clauses, restrictive and non-restrictive:

> **Restrictive**
>
> defines the meaning of a noun or noun phrase and **provides necessary information** about the noun in the sentence
>
> e.g.
>
> - The student who sits in the back of the room asks a lot of questions.

> **Non-restrictive**
>
> adds additional information to a sentence. A non-restrictive clause can be omitted from the sentence.
>
> e.g.
>
> - I want to thank my father, Mark Smith, for all of his love and support.
> - I want to thank my father for all of his love and support.

Some information taken from [Grammar: Relative, Restrictive, and Nonrestrictive Clauses](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses).

[Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040811/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/relative-clauses) states that:

> You do not need to put a comma before restrictive relative clauses.

[Kentlaw.edu](http://www.kentlaw.edu/academics/lrw/grinker/LwtaClauses__Restrictive_and_Nonrest.htm) states that:

> Place proper punctuation around nonrestrictive clauses, but do not place punctuation around restrictive clauses.

In this case, your sentence is a **non-restrictive clause** and therefore **needs** proper punctuation, so it's best to place those commas.

*Note that having the non-restrictive clause at the end of the sentence still requires a comma and period*

Comment: Depends whether the _which is popular..._ clause is intended to identify the restaurant or not. "Have you been to _that_ restaurant (pointing to it), that's so popular with young people?" or "Have you been to the restaurant that's so popular with young people - I forget its name?"